# Facebook Like: specify thumbnail image for likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have SPA that uses hash-tag URLs for identifying content (`#/resource/id`), I've added like button and it works, but how do I specify thumbnail, description etc?

From what I've read I should use

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/site/preview.png"/>
```

but I have a static page without any back end + I need to change it depending on which content is loaded. What should I do?

**UPDATE:** I've found answer: [Facebook Like Button refresh after AJAX-Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663540/facebook-like-button-refresh-after-ajax-load)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your meta tags dynamic you will need to use backend code, such as PHP or ASP. 
There really is no other way to make the header of the document dynamic.

---

PHP example:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['myparam']) && $_GET['myparam']==='big'){
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/site/preview_big.png"/>';
}else{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/site/preview_little.png"/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't. Long story, but there's no backend on target host. There's another network I'm integrating with: VK (Russian  Facebook analogue). And it provides ability to pass preview URL, title and description during widget initialization. Is there something similar for Facebook like widget?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to find a way to pass in a good URL to your image. Facebook takes this tag, goes to your site, and gets your image.