# AJAX reload facebook button | style of facebook button like

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, facebook, button

i've the following question:

**First:** My homepage is AJAX driven. Means on click in the menu the content is loaded into a div and the browser history is manipulated. It works very well and I am proud of me doing this. :)

But: Now I added the facebook recommend/like button to the page. I can not reload this button as well when I reload the content. Because then the needed facebook scripts will not be executed. that means the like button does not work anymore. If I do not reload it with the content the button points to the former URL and the counting box shows the likes of the former page. Is there a workaround for this?

**Second:** I tried to style this button. I even tried to style it with jQuery/Javascript but all this functions doesnt work. It seems as facebook found a way to disable all javaScript manipulation on his button. Is there a working workaround for this? I tried some things I found on the internet...Also I need to disable the comment box which is showed when a user likes the page. right now I am doing this by setting the iframe to overflow hidden and the size of it to a right value. so I am just hiding it, what means this is not a god solution for me.

Would be really great if someone knows a solution or even could point me in the right direction!

Thanks a lot!
Falk

Comment: What exactly have you tried to change? what kind of "javascript manipulation" are you trying to do on the button?

Comment: *Be specific* and share some code.

Comment: Ok I found a solution to refresh the button after reloading the content. You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663540/facebook-like-button-refresh-after-ajax-load Still I need to style my button. I dont think its impossible. Nothing is impossible. Maybe someone knows how to execute the click on the button via javascript. Because then I could just show a own picture to click for the user and hide the original button. Will that be a way? I wasn't successfull with. Would be really great if a javascript specialist could help me out! :) thanks a lot.