# facebook like and share button javascript updating my web page content like reloading a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

Hello Everyone i am stuck here. can't find out why this is happening.
facebook like and share button javascript updating my web page content like reloading a page.

```
(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

this script i am using in my site.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href=" https://www.facebook.com/example" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Comment: could you please put html here

Comment: Maybe this will help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663540/facebook-like-button-refresh-after-ajax-load

Comment: same thing started happening to me today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `data-height="20px" data-width="48px"` to the button code fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This is really work thanks bro. do you know reason why facebook doing that  ?

Comment: It could be some kind of bug on their side.

Comment: Crazy ! That bug wasn't there the day before yesterday. Thx @DenisPshenov !