# Not sure where to look to learn how to use javascript to create my own "like" buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make "like" buttons on my site which basically submit a form without refreshing the entire page as it does now. I was thinking of using iframes, but I'm not sure if that is a great idea. I'm not sure where to look or what to search, but I can't seem to find any tutorials. Where should I look?

Comment: you should look up things like [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and perhaps [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/04/exactly-twitter-like-follow-and-remove.html). It uses JQuery and Ajax to create the kinds of buttons you're looking for. It uses Twitter's "Follow/remove" idea as an example but that is virtually identical to Like/Unlike at the client. And here's an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219729/how-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-to-an-ajax-driven-page) with a number of JQuery-based solutions.